# How to find an ip of connected vnc client from vncserver log?

Tags: vnc, logging

I run the vncserver using vnc4server.

I take a look in ~/.vnc/ubuntu:1.log

It only show something like this.

```
Sat Oct  6 20:40:12 2012
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::2043
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Sat Oct  6 20:40:14 2012
 SConnection: AuthFailureException: Authentication failure
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::2043 (Authentication failure)

Sat Oct  6 20:40:16 2012
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::2048
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
```

How do I find the ip of connected vnc client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the netstat command to see what open network connections there are.

```
sudo netstat -a | grep *vnc port number*
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, because by definition logs are for events having occurred in the past, whereas netstat is for real-time monitoring.